# Whatsapp business API - message reaction not working

Tags: php, whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I am having trouble to add a reaction to a message through the whatsapp API.
I am receiving an good response like the one in the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/send-messages/#reaction-messages)

I am posting to `https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/{fromNumber}/messages` with the following data:

```
{
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "to": {toNumber},
  "type": "reaction",
  "reaction": {
    "message_id": {messageID",
    "emoji": ""
  }
}
```

And receiving a good response:

```
{
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "contacts": [
    {
      "input": {toNumber},
      "wa_id": {toNumber}
    }
  ],
  "messages": [
    {
      "id": {responseWaId}
    }
  ]
}
```

But sadly no reaction to the message is given

I am using PHP:

```
/**
 * Markeer bericht met reactie
 *
 * @param string $toNumber
 * @param string $message
 * @return int
 */
public function markMessageWithEmoji(string $messageId)
{
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/{$this->fromNumber}/messages";

    $response = Http::withHeaders([
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->whatsappToken,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ])->post($url, [
        'messaging_product' => 'whatsapp',
        'recipient_type' => 'individual',
        'to' => $this->toNumber,
        'type' => 'reaction',
        'reaction' => [
            'message_id' => $messageId,
            'emoji' => '',
        ],
    ]);

    return $response->status();
}
```

I am sure the message id is correct, since I use the same ID to set the received message as read and this works as expected

Comment: What are you receiving in webhook notifications?